# Can I make part of an array final / unchangeable?

Tags: java

Hello I have a 2D array of StringBuilder, Im using it to draw a game board, is there any way to make part of it (part of the StringBuilder in a known location) unchangeable ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: give us some example of what you need

Comment: Arrays in java are always mutable

Comment: I don't really get why array of `StringBuilder`. Are you sure it's the best way to do what you want?

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what your game board looks like and why a `StringBuilder[][]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is "no", there's no way to do this in Java.  You'll have to encapsulate the array inside another class, then implement code to make parts of that array unchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying your data type is `StringBuilder[][]`?  And what specifically are you trying to make immutable?  An entire row in that 2D array?  Or a single StringBuilder entry?  If you can provide a bit more detail, my guess is there might be a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

In lieu of extra information, I'll try my best to answer the question as you've posted it.

Arrays, by default, are mutable, and there's not much you can do about that.  Even the `final` keyword in Java isn't a guarantee that the contents of an object won't change; it only guarantees that a new object won't be created in its place.

If using 3rd party libraries is an option, you could look into some of the ImmutableCollection types in Google Guava: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained, but I'm not entirely sure that's what you're asking.